# MongoDB - Group by number, and then match by max of all groups

Tags: mongodb

In my MondoDB, I would like to group my data by a number (machine_quality), and then compare this number with maximum value of **ALL** `machine_quality`, not just maximum value per every single group.

**My nonworking query**:

```js
db.records.aggregate([
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$machine_quality',
            'total': {'$sum': 1}
        }
    },
    {
        '$match': {
            '_id': {
                '$gte': {
                    '$subtract': [{'$max': '$_id'}, 3]
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Question:**

Part of query `{'$max': '$_id'}` only reffers to each group separately, and therefore will be always equal to group's `_id`. However I would like max to compare with maximum `_id` across **ALL** groups. Is there any convenient way to do that?

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use `$facet`, this way you can do 2 "parallel looking" group into 1 pipeline. (the second group will be your group, group by null is to find the global max)

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7mKH2927WhQ)

Query (after the facet,you can unwind your groups)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "global_max": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "m": {
              "$max": "$machine_quality"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "groups": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$machine_quality",
            "names": {
              "$push": "$name"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$addFields": {
            "machine_quality": "$_id"
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "global_max": {
        "$let": {
          "vars": {
            "v": {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                "$global_max",
                0
              ]
            }
          },
          "in": "$$v.m"
        }
      },
      "groups": 1
    }
  }
])
```

This has the limitations of `$facet` 16MB document size [see](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/#considerations)